# I have a LegendItemEntity, how do I get the LegendItem?

Tags: jfreechart

I have code that hides/shows a series when the LegendItemEntity is clicked.  The code works, except I use the index of the series as the index of the LegendItem in the LegendItemCollection.  The problem is that sometimes there are more series than LegendItems and their respective indices are not the same.  How do I get the LegendItem given that I have the LegendItemEntity?

```
private final ChartMouseListener chartMouseListener = new ChartMouseListener() {

    public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent cme) {
        ChartEntity entity = cme.getEntity();
        if (entity instanceof LegendItemEntity) {
            LegendItemEntity itemEntity = (LegendItemEntity) entity;
            int index = dataset.getSeriesIndex(itemEntity.getSeriesKey());
            XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
            XYItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
            renderer.setSeriesVisible(index, !renderer.isSeriesVisible(index));
            LegendItem legendItem = plot.getLegendItems().get(index);
            if (renderer.isSeriesVisible(index)) {
                legendItem.setLinePaint(renderer.getSeriesPaint(index));
            } else {
                legendItem.setLinePaint(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
    }

    public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent cme) {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `renderer.getLegendItem()`. The result will be `null` for a non-visible series. Given a `JFreeChart chart`, a `chartMouseClicked()` implementation might look like this:

```
@Override
public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getEntity() instanceof LegendItemEntity itemEntity) {
        var key = itemEntity.getSeriesKey();
        var dataset = (XYDataset) itemEntity.getDataset();
        int seriesIndex = dataset.indexOf(key);
        var plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        var datasetIndex = plot.indexOf(dataset);
        var renderer = plot.getRenderer();
        LegendItem legendItem = renderer.getLegendItem(datasetIndex, seriesIndex);
        System.out.print(key + " " + datasetIndex + " " + seriesIndex);
        System.out.println(" " + legendItem);
    }
}
```